# JavaScriptSerializer for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am trying to convert my .NET 4.0 class library to Windows Phone 8 class library to use it in my app. It turns out to be there is no JavaScriptSerializer available in Windows Phone 8 SDK. I am actually trying to deserialise my HttpClient response to my class object. How can I achieve that using windows phone 8 SDK.

Below is the code that I used in my .NET Class library

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dataObject = serializer.Deserialize<MyResponseClassObject>(result);
return dataObject;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [JSON.NET](http://json.net/) instead of `JavaScriptSerializer`: it has better performance and supports .NET 2, .NET 3.5, .NET 4, Silverlight and Windows Phone.

Here is the equivalent of your code with JSON.NET:

```
var dataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResponseClassObject>(result);
return dataObject;
```

Comment: Oh...I didn't know that. Thanks for the quick reply. I looked at its documentation and it should solve my problem.